# C++ How to specify cast type at runtime?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to specify at the type `T` at runtime in C++? From [this site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/dynamic_pointer_cast/):

```
template <class T, class U>
  shared_ptr<T> dynamic_pointer_cast (const shared_ptr<U>& sp) noexcept;
```

I want to be able to decide at runtime which class to cast a pointer to. I can do it in Django/Python, but need to do it in C++.  Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Adding a little more context so maybe answers can contain more than "no, you can't" ;)

I need to be able to overload the return type from a function, have an `auto` return type, or return a heterogeneous collection of items and flag the correct one using a union or a struct, or ... something ...
I'm not able to use boost or anything later than C++14, so have no access to the `std::variant` functionality.

For example:

```
typeAorB getSomething(int i){
   A a;
   B b;

   if(i>1) return a;
   return b;
}
```

Comment: Nope. Template instantiation happens at compile-time, so you need all of the information at that point.

Comment: C++ is statically typed. This means that all types are fixed at compile-time. You can't change the type of anything at run time.

Comment: You should tell more about what you are actually trying to accomplish. Casting a pointer is rarely the right way to do it in C++.

Comment: How would you do it in Python, which doesn't have pointers and casts?

Comment: cplusplus.com is not "the manual". It's not written by experts but by "enthusiasts", and it's not very good.

Comment: A better reference site: https://cppreference.com/

Comment: `no access to std::variant` But you are asking how to return what would essentially be a variant type. If you don't have access to the `std` one then you'll need to roll your own.

Comment: Would a `switch` statement work for you?

Comment: Thanks @dvix "then you'll need to roll your own".  Yes.  That's kinda my question ... what's the workaround that would replace the variant type?

Comment: @Chipster ... how would you use it to return the item from a function?  I can use switch (or anything else) to create the item, but I can't return it without having to specify its type?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Better ... possibly ... harder to read ... certainly!  But thanks, I've looked there too :)

Comment: @user2662404 I was thinking on the other side of the return possibly. Are there any issues with you doing that?

Comment: @Chipster Yes, that's my plan Z ... I really don't want the users of this API to have to write a switch for all possible cases each time they want to retrieve an item :(

Comment: @user2662404 `replace the variant type` Find an implementation of `std::variant` that doesn't use language features beyond C++14 and take inspiration from it. A quick search found [MPark.Variant](https://github.com/mpark/variant) for example. P.S. When you '@' ping someone TAB works to auto-complete, and also avoids misspellings ;-)

Comment: Thanks @dxiv Tab-able goodness I didn't know about!  We're trying to keep our dependencies super-low (also the reason for not using version 17), so wouldn't include anything directly.  I'll have a read of your suggestion though, thanks.